# terminal mode (with -nw) vs gui mode

Tags: spacemacs, tramp

Now I read lots of good stuff about spacemacs and want to try it out.

I like the way iterm2 separates hosts/projects cleanly.
Can I use iterm2 + spacemacs (maybe in terminal mode?)

Or do I lose most of spacemacs functionality if I don't use gui

Comment: Your question risks being deleted because it is too broad. Please narrow the focus, to pose one specific question (e.g. how to ___). Broad questions are more appropriate for a discussion site such as Reddit. Thx.

Comment: Different people have different opinions / tolerances / networks.  You're the only one who can decide whether using tramp is an acceptable experience for you.

Comment: @phils so is it true that tramp is actually slower than sshing in and opening up emacs there on the remote machine? (maybe tramp has to go through `connection establishment` step more often than sshing?

Comment: *Personally* I use (and love) tramp for tasks which are only occasional.  Any host where I'm doing a lot of work in Emacs has Emacs installed on it, and I run it directly on that machine (with GUI frames if it's on the local network, and terminal frames if it's a slower network).  Do what works best for you.  The nice thing is that Emacs supports numerous different approaches.

Comment: Tramp definitely has overheads; it couldn't *not* have any.  If ControlMaster is available then it will re-use connections by default, so hopefully you won't be seeing connection handshaking for every action; but it's still having to talk a lot over the network.  If you ssh to the host and run Emacs locally in the terminal, the network usage is purely the terminal I/O (and of course Emacs redisplay in a terminal is pretty network-friendly).

Comment: Plenty of people swear by Tramp for all their use-cases, though.  You really just have to test it again, and decide for yourself.

Comment: @phil thanks for input, can you share one or two aspects of gui that keeps you using tramp if possible? (I haven't used gui version for over 10 years..)

Comment: Well GUI and Tramp are unrelated elements -- you can use Tramp from a terminal frame as easily as from a GUI frame.  The reasons for preferring GUI over terminal tend to be things like additional key bindings, enhanced rendering (images, fonts), and perhaps a smoother interoperability with your window manager.  If you personally don't feel you're missing anything, though, then you're probably not.